# responsive site partially wrong scale

Tags: css, meta

I am working on a responsive site. When i test it in [Responsinator](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jazzguru.nl%2F) it works perfectly. But when i test it on my iphone 5s it looks like this.

[image: http://www.jazzguru.nl/images/foto.PNG]

I used this meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

When I use

```
 initial-scale=1
```

Then everything is 4 times as large as the screen.

Comment: have you tried `<meta content="width" name="MobileOptimized">` ?

Comment: Just tried it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

To:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And let me know if that solved it for you. This works for me on pretty much all devices I tried so far.

Comment: I found this solution when i googled the problem but this results in everything being four times as large as the screen

Comment: Thanks i haddent heard of bootstrap before. There are indeed a lot of css file's. Its more structured for me that way. Is that a bad thing?